# Mosaico extension uses

Tags: extension

Is anyone using Mosaico for designing a newsletter?  Is it easy to use?  Can you send a newsletter directly through mass mail? I would appreciate any comments.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stack Exchange OSRT!  Yes, you can use Mosaico for designing newsletters. Whether it is easy to use is a matter of opinion, but probably most would agree it's pretty straightforward.  You create your newsletter within CiviCRM using the [Mosaico extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/email-template-builder) and then send it out from there.

The main CiviCRM demo sites are not using that extension, but you can watch a quick demo of Mosaico itself and try it on the [Mosaico site](https://mosaico.io/).  Note that the way Mosaico is used within Civi is slightly different but the basic use is the same.

You will also need to [configure your system](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/civimail/) to send email.

Comment: Thank you Adam. I appreciate the information you sent.